# Trying to set my configuration file as a defult configuration file for Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, package.json, configuration-files, installation-package

Is there any way using which we can **force Visual Studio Code Marketplace extension to use our own configuration file instead of their own default .config file upon installation**?
I really want to use my own configuration file for a particular something.

Comment: which `.config` file

Comment: Every extension has their own .config file which contains all the configuration. I simply want the xtension to use my .config file intead of their own

Comment: do you mean `package.json`, where is this `.config` file

Comment: .config file is completely seperate from the package.json file

Comment: It is a configuration file for any extension

Comment: If you install any extension in visual studio code, then you will see "repository" option to the right. Click on that and you will be redirected to all the files that the extension is composed of. Among those files there is one file called .config file which basically defines the default configurations for that particular extension

Comment: the `Repository` link on the Marketplace page directs you to the (mostly) Github page of the extension, in none of the extensions I develop there is `.config` file, show a link of such a repo

Comment: https://github.com/xaverh/vscode-clang-format-provider

In this repository, you can find .clang-format file which basically contains all the configurations

Comment: maybe it is my eyes but `.clang-format` and `.config` look different in name, not all extensions have a `.clang-format` file. The readme of the extension tells you how to configure clang-format in possibly the first paragraph

Comment: a quick look at the source of the ext, the file `.clang-format` is not used anywhere

Comment: If you open .clang-format file, you can see some configurations that has been set already and are required to be used

Comment: where in the extension is this file used, configuration is described on the clang-format website, maybe you can copy paste the `.clang-format` file to your workspace as a starter